# Error: 'In an assignment A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same'

Tags: matlab

Problem: TrajSimilarity is a struct of k elements, I want to put all the value of TrajSimilarity(1,k).aLongestString in a vector/array A. I try using this code but it generate error, can you help me to solve the problem?

Code:

```
for k=1:14
    A(k)=TrajSimilarity(1,k).aLongestString;
    end
```

Error:

```
In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must
be the same
```

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the field name `aLongestString` I assume you are processing strings. In matlab there is no real string data type, instead you are processing arrays of char, for example `hello` is of size `[1 5]`.

Each element of an array can only hold a scalar, for example a number or a character, thus you can not store a string in it. A cell array can hold arbitrary data in it's cell, so try a cell array:

```
n=14
A=cell(n,1)
for k=1:n
    A{k}=TrajSimilarity(1,k).aLongestString;
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TrajSimilarity(1,k).aLongestString
```

is an element-wise product of two vectors, resulting a vector. You want to put it into A(k) which is a scalar. Change the code to this one:

```
A=TrajSimilarity(1,k).aLongestString;
```

Comment: Where do see an element-wise product? Does a dot mean a product?

Comment: Sorry, somehow I saw .*